# Como passar uma função como parâmetro em Action Script?

Tags: actionscript-3

**Alguém sabe me dizer qual tipo de objeto permite eu fazer uma matriz  de valor e uma função parecida com o código abaixo e action script 3?
Se fosse em Java daria pra fazer alguma coisa tipo essa:**

Minha Interface:

```
package test;

public interface MyInterface {

    public void alert();
}
```

E minha classe com a utilização da Interface:

```
package test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, MyInterface> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put(1, new MyInterface() {
            @Override
            public void alert() {
                System.out.println("valor 1");

            }
        });

        map.put(2, new MyInterface() {
            @Override
            public void alert() {
                System.out.println("valor 2");

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Não entendi. A função já existe na tal classe?

Comment: Existe.. eu queria passar qualquer função com argumento da minha matriz entendeu?

pode ser algo desse tipo também..
map.put(valor, alert("teste"));

Comment: Removi minha resposta porque a pergunta agora é outra. Não tinha sacado que era do Map de Java que você estava falando. Vou deixar pra alguém que manja mais Java responder...

Comment: Não cara se voce conhecer algum objeto que eu possa usar ou alguma outra forma, me ajuda ae @bfavaretto

Comment: Cara, meu Java não é dos melhores, e meu AS3 está bem enferrujado, não uso há anos. Mas fiz uma tentativa em uma nova resposta, veja aí se funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tentar usar uma array em vez do `HashMap`, e objetos literais como valor:

```
var map = [];
map.push({
    alert: function() { trace("aaaaa") }
});
map.push({
    alert: function() { trace("bbbbb") }
});
map[0].alert(); // aaaaa
map[1].alert(); // bbbbb
```

Comment: beleza brother, vou testar aqui qualquer coisa eu te falo =D

Comment: Pensei em algumas alternativas, mas não achei uma melhor que essa, rsrs. Seu AS tá enferrujado não!